# About an asymptotic behavior in number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Where can I read about the  asymptotic behavior (with $N$ tending to infinity) of the sum of the fractional parts obtained from dividing $N$ by all prime numbers up to $N$ divided by the number of these numbers?

With respect
Kinunen Alexander
Saint-Petersburg

Comment: In symbols, $(\pi(N))^{-1}\sum_{p\le N}\{N/p\}$ where $p$ runs through primes.

Comment: $\int_0^1 \{\frac{1}{t}\}dt = 1-\gamma$

Answer (score 13):

See [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14000729) of Naslund, specifically Proposition 3. That result, along with the prime number theorem, shows that
$$
\frac{1}{\pi(N)} \sum_{p\leq N} \left\{ \frac{N}{p} \right\} \sim 1-\gamma,
$$
where $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: $\int_0^1 \{\frac{1}{t}\}dt = 1-\gamma$